# Angular - Show component if checkbox checked. Each checkbox has separate component

Tags: angular, checkbox

Let say I have 4 checkboxes.

```
<mat-checkbox>1</mat-checkbox>
<component-1></component-1>
<mat-checkbox>2</mat-checkbox>
<component-2></component-2>
<mat-checkbox>3</mat-checkbox>
<component-3></component-3>
<mat-checkbox>4</mat-checkbox>
<component-4></component-4>
```

Each `mat-checkbox` has its own separate `component`.
When the user checked any of the first 3 checkboxes it will show/load the component, but if the user checked 4th `mat-checkbox` it will uncheck the above three `mat-checkbox` causing their components to hide and show only 4th component

CASE1: - user may check any of the first three together.

CASE2:- user can check either any of the first three or fourth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6vza6f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) 
Please let me know if I am missing anything inadvertently. 
I have achieved it this way:

Master app Template:

```
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<mat-checkbox #checkOne (change)="OnChkChanged(1)">1</mat-checkbox>
<component-1 *ngIf="showOne"></component-1>

<mat-checkbox #checkTwo (change)="OnChkChanged(2)">2</mat-checkbox>
<component-2 *ngIf="showTwo"></component-2>

<mat-checkbox #checkThree (change)="OnChkChanged(3)">3</mat-checkbox>
<component-3 *ngIf="showThree"></component-3>

<mat-checkbox #checkFour (change)="OnChkChanged(4)">4</mat-checkbox>
<component-4 *ngIf="showFour"></component-4>
```

Master app Component:

```
import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  @ViewChild("checkOne") checkOne: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("checkTwo") checkTwo: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("checkThree") checkThree: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("checkFour") checkFour: ElementRef;

  showOne = false;
  showTwo = false;
  showThree = false;
  showFour = false;

  OnChkChanged(id: number) {
    if (id === 1) {
      this.showOne = !this.showOne;
    }
    if (id === 2) {
      this.showTwo = !this.showTwo;
    }
    if (id === 3) {
      this.showThree = !this.showThree;
    }
    if (id === 4) {
      this.showFour = !this.showFour;
      if (this.showFour === true) {
        this.uncheckAllThree();
      }
    }
  }

  uncheckAllThree() {
    this.checkOne["checked"] = false;
    this.showOne = false;
    this.checkTwo["checked"] = false;
    this.showTwo = false;
    this.checkThree["checked"] = false;
    this.showThree = false;
  }
}
```

ComponentOne:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-1',
  template: '<h3>I am Component 1</h3>',
})
export class ComponentOne  {
  
}
```

ComponentTwo:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-2',
  template: '<h3>I am Component 2</h3>',
})
export class ComponentTwo  {
  
}
```

ComponentThree:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-3',
  template: '<h3>I am Component 3</h3>',
})
export class ComponentThree  {
  
}
```

ComponentFour:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-4',
  template: '<h3>I am Component 4</h3>',
})
export class ComponentFour  {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from the question is that first three checkboxes have no impact on the fourth checkbox but the fourth checkbox have impact on all above three checkboxes.

Solution:

The fourth checkbox when clicked you have to use @Output() to pass event to parent component and then either you can use properties or call methods inside the three separate components in which you have the other checkboxes.

You have to change properties in case you are handling the data from parent and you would have to call method in case you handling the data inside each component.

If you didn't get what I am saying then it would be great if you could show us an example of your work in https://stackblitz.com/

P.S: There could be multiple solutions.